# How to loop through all sheets in all workbooks within a folder

Tags: vba, excel

I use a macro to make changes on each sheet of each workbook in a given folder on my computer.

**Sequence of events:**

1. Open each Excel file within the user-selected folder
2. Perform a task on each sheet in the workbook
3. Save the file
4. Close the workbook

The macro doesn't work. The problem seems to be arising from `Selection.AutoFilter`.

```vb
Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder()
    'OBJECTIVE: To loop through all Excel files in a user specified folder and perform a set task on them
    'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim Current As Worksheet
    Dim myPath As String
    Dim myFile As String
    Dim myExtension As String
    Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

    'Optimize Macro Speed
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
    Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With FldrPicker
        .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

    'In Case of Cancel
    NextCode:
    myPath = myPath
    If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

    'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
    myExtension = "*.xlsx*"

    'Target Path with Ending Extention
    myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

    'Loop through each Excel file in folder
    Do While myFile <> ""
        'Set variable equal to opened workbook
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)
    
        'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
        DoEvents
    
        'Task: For each worksheet, delete the first column, make A1 bold, and filter and remove all rows in column A that do not contain anything

        For Each Current In wb.Worksheets
            Columns("A:A").Select
            Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
            Range("A1").Select
            Selection.Font.Bold = True
            Selection.AutoFilter
            ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$5000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="="
            Rows("2:2").Select
            Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
            Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
            ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
            Range("A1").Select
         Next
    
        'Save and Close Workbook
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
      
        'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
        DoEvents

        'Get next file name
        myFile = Dir
    Loop

    'Message Box when tasks are completed
    MsgBox "Task Complete!"

    ResetSettings:
    'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm no Excel VBA expert but it seems you never use your workbook `wb` to go through the worksheets? maybe something like `For Each Current In wb.Worksheets` or how does the loop know what file you're working with? `Worksheets` might be your currently opened file maybe :)

Comment: It seems like the problem arises from Selection.AutoFilter

Comment: [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba/10718179#10718179) will get you started

Comment: Thank you Siddharth, I've tried converting the code using With and eliminating the .Select, .Selection and .Active but I still don't get the intended result.

Comment: @Varunyou should update your code with the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try it like this.

```
Sub Example()
    Dim MyPath As String, FilesInPath As String
    Dim MyFiles() As String, Fnum As Long
    Dim mybook As Workbook
    Dim CalcMode As Long
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim ErrorYes As Boolean

    'Fill in the path\folder where the files are
    MyPath = "C:\Users\Ron\test"

    'Add a slash at the end if the user forget it
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    End If

    'If there are no Excel files in the folder exit the sub
    FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath & "*.xl*")
    If FilesInPath = "" Then
        MsgBox "No files found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Fill the array(myFiles)with the list of Excel files in the folder
    Fnum = 0
    Do While FilesInPath <> ""
        Fnum = Fnum + 1
        ReDim Preserve MyFiles(1 To Fnum)
        MyFiles(Fnum) = FilesInPath
        FilesInPath = Dir()
    Loop

    'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Loop through all files in the array(myFiles)
    If Fnum > 0 Then
        For Fnum = LBound(MyFiles) To UBound(MyFiles)
            Set mybook = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFiles(Fnum))
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not mybook Is Nothing Then


                'Change cell value(s) in one worksheet in mybook
                On Error Resume Next
                With mybook.Worksheets(1)
                    If .ProtectContents = False Then
                        .Range("A1").Value = "My New Header"
                    Else
                        ErrorYes = True
                    End If
                End With


                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    ErrorYes = True
                    Err.Clear
                    'Close mybook without saving
                    mybook.Close savechanges:=False
                Else
                    'Save and close mybook
                    mybook.Close savechanges:=True
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0
            Else
                'Not possible to open the workbook
                ErrorYes = True
            End If

        Next Fnum
    End If

    If ErrorYes = True Then
        MsgBox "There are problems in one or more files, possible problem:" _
             & vbNewLine & "protected workbook/sheet or a sheet/range that not exist"
    End If

    'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With
End Sub
```

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win010.htm